# rocket.chat snap doesn't start

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

I installed Rocket.chat with snap, but the caddy service never starts and the web is not working (I think because of caddy):

```
costales@ubuntu:~$ sudo systemctl status snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo.service  | grep -E 'Active|Loaded'
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-mongo.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-03-19 19:10:37 CET; 3min 17s ago
costales@ubuntu:~$ sudo systemctl status snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server.service  | grep -E 'Active|Loaded'
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2017-03-19 19:10:38 CET; 3min 24s ago
costales@ubuntu:~$ sudo systemctl restart snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-caddy.service 
costales@ubuntu:~$ sudo systemctl status snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-caddy.service 
● snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-caddy.service - Service for snap application rocketchat-server.rocketchat-caddy
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-caddy.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-03-19 19:14:19 CET; 234ms ago
  Process: 2641 ExecStart=/usr/bin/snap run rocketchat-server.rocketchat-caddy (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2641 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 19 19:14:19 ubuntu systemd[1]: snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-caddy.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 19 19:14:19 ubuntu systemd[1]: snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-caddy.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 19 19:14:19 ubuntu systemd[1]: snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-caddy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 19 19:14:19 ubuntu systemd[1]: snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-caddy.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 19 19:14:19 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Service for snap application rocketchat-server.rocketchat-caddy.
Mar 19 19:14:19 ubuntu systemd[1]: snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-caddy.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 19 19:14:19 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Service for snap application rocketchat-server.rocketchat-caddy.
costales@ubuntu:~$
```

I tried to remove and reinstall again, but same result all the time. Any idea please? Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to install and use other snaps? If so, this might be an issue particular to Rocket.Chat, and will be best addressed at their forums.

Comment: Does rocketchat actually work? If you go to localhost:3000 do you see the rocketchat login? Seems the caddy service is merely a transparent proxy on port 8080. If that port it already taken, that may be why it doesn't start.

Answer (score 1):

It's weird, but after install (or reboot the server) you need to start with `https://<yourIP>:3000` instead of `http://<yourIP>:3000`. After that, try `http://<yourIP>:3000` and it will work.